# Grabbing time from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know how it is possible to grab the time from a UIDatePicker in Count Down Timer mode, and then display that while counting down in a Hour:Minute:Second format. My biggest issue is actually grabbing the time from the Date Picker. As I'm not really to sure how to start that.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

stopWatchPicker.countDownDuration = 60.0;

    if timerCount == 0 { 
        timerRunning = false
    }
}

var timerCount = 60 //set to 60 for testing purposes
var timer = Timer() 
var timerRunning = false 


@IBOutlet weak var stopWatchPicker: UIDatePicker!  
@IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if timerRunning == false {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning = true
    }
}
@IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    timerRunning = false
}

func updateCounter() {
    timerCount -= 1
    countDownLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"

    if timerCount == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Just grab it! You fetch the date picker's `countDownDuration`. That is the number of seconds the user wants. Now start counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grab the countDownDuration from the stopWatchPicker and assign it to the timerCount variable.

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  if timerRunning == false {
    timerCount = stopWatchPicker.countDownDuration
    timerRunning = true
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }
}
```

Cheers!